# WIX Property as Integer

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am trying to set a a property to configure the IIS:Website ConnectionTimeout value on a new website that gets created during setup.

However I am unable to, as the value for ConnectionTimeout must be an integer, not string.

In my product.wxs I have the following:

```
<Control Id="IisConnectionTimeoutLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="164" Width="100" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="Connection Timeout (sec):" />
<Control Id="IisConnectionTimeoutEdit" Type="Edit" X="45" Y="176" Width="220" Height="18" Property="IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT" Text="{80}" Integer="yes"  />
```

And in my IisConfiguration.wxs I have the following:

```
<Property Id="IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT" Value="300" />
<iis:WebSite Id="EersWebsite" Description="[IIS_WEBSITENAME]" ConfigureIfExists="yes" Directory="WEBINSTALLDIR" DirProperties="EersWebsiteDirProperties" ConnectionTimeout="[IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT]">
```

When I build the project I get the following:

> The 'ConnectionTimeout' attribute is invalid - The value
>   '[IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT]' is invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:nonNegativeInteger' - The string
>   '[IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT]' is not a valid Integer value.
>
> The iis:WebSite/@ConnectionTimeout attribute's value,
>   '[IIS_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT]', is not a legal integer value.  Legal
>   integer values are from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, the value of the `<iis:WebSite>`'s `ConnectionTimeout` attribute expects the integer value. The `nonNegativeInteger` is not a [`Formatted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) type, which knows how to extract values out of properties provided in square brackets.

Hence, I don't think you have a way here apart from providing the hard-coded value...

Alternatively, you can create a custom action, which calls for `appcmd.exe`, and provide the required timeout value in the command-line, and schedule this action deferred after `ConfitureIIs`... But the efforts seem much bigger than the benefit...