# window height and width in include file

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a generic wxi file where I keep all common data across all wxs files.

I would like to keep there width and height of the install UI window as well.

When I tried to do so, it gives me an error that is not type of integer.

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639407/wix-property-as-integer and see if that helps any..

Comment: The install UI window is usually not dynamically sized, and MSI does not support dynamic creation of controls, yet you can hide/show some of the controls depending on a condition. You design a page of the setup wizard just like a dialog window, you put the controls onto it. Additionally, the *default* size of setup UI pages is the same as the size of the wizards in Windows XP because Windows Installer UI mimics the wizard interface so that it looks familiar.

Comment: Please give us more details on how you would like to use these value, a code sample would also be a plus.